# Faster GCD(n, m) in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

I'm working on something that's going to need to use the GCD algorithm quite a bit, and I'd like it to be as fast as possible. I've tried the normal method, binary method, and a memoisation method I thought would work better than it did. I copied the binary method from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm), with minor tweaks.

I've been using a class called TestGCD for testing, here's the whole thing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestGCD
{
  private static class Pair<A>
  {
    private final A a_one;
    private final A a_two;

    public Pair(A a_one, A a_two)
    {
      this.a_one = a_one;
      this.a_two = a_two;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
      if (this == object)
        return true;
      if (object == null)
        return false;
      if (!(object instanceof Pair))
        return false;

      final Pair other = (Pair) object;

      if (a_one == null)
        if (other.a_one != null)
          return false;
      if (a_two == null)
        if (other.a_two != null)
          return false;
      if (a_one.equals(other.a_one))
        if (a_two.equals(other.a_two))
          return true;
      if (a_one.equals(other.a_two))
        if (a_two.equals(other.a_one))
          return true;

      return false;
    }

    public A getFirst()
    {
      return a_one;
    }

    public A getSecond()
    {
      return a_two;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;

      final int aOneHash = a_one == null ? 0 : a_one.hashCode();
      final int aTwoHash = a_two == null ? 0 : a_two.hashCode();

      int resultOneWay = prime * result + aOneHash;
      resultOneWay += prime * result + aTwoHash;

      int resultOtherWay = prime * result + aTwoHash;
      resultOtherWay += prime * result + aOneHash;

      result += resultOneWay + resultOtherWay;
      return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return String.format("%s, %s", a_one, a_two);
    }
  }

  private final static Map<Pair<Integer>, Integer> STORAGE = new HashMap<>();

  private static void addNewPairs(List<Pair<Integer>> newPairs, int result)
  {
    for (final Pair<Integer> pair : newPairs)
      STORAGE.put(pair, result);
  }

  private static int gcd(int x, int y)
  {
    if (x == 0)
      return y;
    if (y == 0)
      return x;

    int gcdX = Math.abs(x);
    int gcdY = Math.abs(y);

    if (gcdX == 1 || gcdY == 1)
      return 1;

    while (gcdX != gcdY)
      if (gcdX > gcdY)
        gcdX -= gcdY;
      else
        gcdY -= gcdX;

    return gcdX;
  }

  private static int gcdBinary(int x, int y)
  {
    int shift;

    /* GCD(0, y) == y; GCD(x, 0) == x, GCD(0, 0) == 0 */
    if (x == 0)
      return y;
    if (y == 0)
      return x;

    int gcdX = Math.abs(x);
    int gcdY = Math.abs(y);

    if (gcdX == 1 || gcdY == 1)
      return 1;

    /* Let shift := lg K, where K is the greatest power of 2 dividing both x and y. */
    for (shift = 0; ((gcdX | gcdY) & 1) == 0; ++shift)
    {
      gcdX >>= 1;
      gcdY >>= 1;
    }

    while ((gcdX & 1) == 0)
      gcdX >>= 1;

    /* From here on, gcdX is always odd. */
    do
    {
      /* Remove all factors of 2 in gcdY -- they are not common */
      /* Note: gcdY is not zero, so while will terminate */
      while ((gcdY & 1) == 0)
        /* Loop X */
        gcdY >>= 1;

      /*
       * Now gcdX and gcdY are both odd. Swap if necessary so gcdX <= gcdY,
       * then set gcdY = gcdY - gcdX (which is even). For bignums, the
       * swapping is just pointer movement, and the subtraction
       * can be done in-place.
       */
      if (gcdX > gcdY)
      {
        final int t = gcdY;
        gcdY = gcdX;
        gcdX = t;
      }  // Swap gcdX and gcdY.
      gcdY = gcdY - gcdX;                       // Here gcdY >= gcdX.
    }while (gcdY != 0);

    /* Restore common factors of 2 */
    return gcdX << shift;
  }

  private static int gcdMemoised(int x, int y)
  {
    if (x == 0)
      return y;
    if (y == 0)
      return x;

    int gcdX = Math.abs(x);
    int gcdY = Math.abs(y);

    if (gcdX == 1 || gcdY == 1)
      return 1;

    final List<Pair<Integer>> newPairs = new ArrayList<>();
    while (gcdX != gcdY)
    {
      final Pair<Integer> pair = new Pair<>(gcdX, gcdY);
      final Integer result = STORAGE.get(pair);
      if (result != null)
      {
        addNewPairs(newPairs, result);
        return result;
      }
      else
        newPairs.add(pair);

      if (gcdX > gcdY)
        gcdX -= gcdY;
      else
        gcdY -= gcdX;
    }

    addNewPairs(newPairs, gcdX);

    return gcdX;
  }
```

So is there a way of making this algorithm faster or is the original version the fastest I'm going to get? No suggestions of using another language please, I'm looking for an algorithm improvement. Clearly my memoisation attempt was an utter failure, but maybe someone here can see a flaw/improve on it.

Comment: This should be of interest: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/MathExplained

Comment: Please use Caliper to benchmark your code. These numbers are meaningless.

Comment: You're looking about how to create a micro benchmark, and there are some problems there, basically in `main` method like no warmup phase and that stuff.

Comment: There's also [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), which I haven't used.

Comment: Please present measurement results suggesting GCD performance indeed matters. If you aren't worried about disclosing the application, please do so. (In early SPARC days, I sped up modulus some (finding non-restoring division to be faster than using the divide step instruction …) - between profiling time-consuming program runs and finding the step necessitating the modulus operations ill-conceived in the first place.)

Comment: @greybeard sure, but the JVM has JIT which speeds up the execution of code after some executions, which means the results cannot be part of a real benchmark.

Comment: Instead of successive subtrations gcdY = gcdY - gcdX, use the remainder  gcdY = gcdY % gcdX. It is also unnecessary to compare the two numbers on every iteration, as you always obtain gcdY < gcdX.

Comment: It's not super important, really. It'll just make the final thing feel more sluggish. I asked this for curiosity's sake more than anything, but I'm guessing a unique, faster algorithm doesn't exist, else it would have been suggested already. I'll settle for what I've got I think, and look at Guava and implement the change suggested by Yves.

Comment: Testing for values < 1000 is not enough. With such small numbers, you don't really explore the behavior of the algorithm. Also a good idea to try two successive Fibonacci numbers, known to correspond to worst cases.

Comment: Can someone edit my post to remove the rubbish-benchmarking information and main method? Clearly that was a bad idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Euclid's algorithm. It is very simple to implement and it is more efficient. Here is a code for it:

```
static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        int t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t % b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

The time complexity is `O(log(A + B))`, while the algorithms you are using are `O(A + B)`. It scales better and is efficient for small `a` and `b`, too.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for. Unfortunate I made it look like I was looking for micro-optimisations by posting the binary version and stuff, I was really looking for improved big-O. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jxek i guess complexity is Olog(min(a,b)) :/

Answer (score 1):

[Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) used by author of the question (subtraction-based version) and accepted answer (mod-based) both seems to be quite not as efficient as [Binary GCD Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm), so here it's code in java (taken from wikipidea)

```
static long gcd(long u, long v) {
    int shift;

    if (u == 0) return v;
    if (v == 0) return u;

    for (shift = 0; ((u | v) & 1) == 0; ++shift) {
        u >>= 1;
        v >>= 1;
    }

    while ((u & 1) == 0) {
        u >>= 1;
    }

    do {
        while ((v & 1) == 0) {
            v >>= 1;
        }

        if (u > v) {
            long t = v;
            v = u;
            u = t;
        }

        v = v - u;
    } while (v != 0);

    return u << shift;
}
```

However, Binary algorithm is not the fastest gcd algorithm. More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Efficiency).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, on the same lines as @ILoveCoding

```
public static long gcd(long first, long second) {

    long big = 0;
    long small = 0;

    if(first > second) {
        big=first;
        small=second;
    }
    else {
        big=second;
        small=first;
    }

    long temp = big % small;
    while( (temp) > 1 ) {
        big = small;
        small = temp;
        temp = big % small;
    }

    if( temp == 0 ) {
        return small ;
    }
    else if( temp == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1; // will never occur. hack for compilation error.
    }

}
```

Edit: Test cases !

```
System.out.println( gcd(10L, 5L));
System.out.println( gcd(11L, 7L));
System.out.println( gcd(15L, 21L));
System.out.println( gcd(-2L, -5L));
System.out.println( gcd(-2L, 2L));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Euclidean** Algorithm for GCD

**The algorithm is based on below facts.**

1. If we subtract smaller number from larger (we reduce larger number),
   GCD doesn’t change. So if we keep subtracting repeatedly the larger
   of two, we end up with GCD.
2. Now instead of subtraction, if we divide smaller number, the
   algorithm stops when we find remainder 0.

**Code:**

```
        import java.util.*; 
        import java.lang.*; 
        class GFG 
        { 
            public static int gcd(int a, int b) 
            { 
                if (a == 0) 
                    return b; 

                return gcd(b%a, a); 
            } 

     public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int a = 10, b = 15, g; 
        g = gcd(a, b); 
        System.out.println("GCD(" + a +  " , " + b+ ") = " + g); 

    } 
}
```

> Time Complexity: O(Log min(a, b))